# Can non-citizens sell paper certificated UK stocks?

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, canada

I inherited BATS shares listed on the LSE. I’m a Canadian citizen, and the shares are paper certificated. I’ve been trying to sell them for a year with no luck. Can I sell them without naturalizing in the UK? If so, how?

Comment: What problems are you running into?

Comment: You might find this an interesting read: https://the-international-investor.com/sell-foreign-stocks (and I note near the end it mentions "Readers resident in Canada have said they were able to sell foreign shares through banks such as HSBC.").

Comment: Hi timday, yes I have seen this page before.  Unfortunately, though I’m a Canadian citizen, because I’m not a resident in Canada, I haven’t been able to open a new account with HSBC in Canada.  I would need to open an account in Canada as a non-resident, but from previous experience it is very difficult to work with HSBC in Canada if you are a high-net worth client or fall into one of their targeted product client groups.  I have tried HSBC before, but was unable to open an account with them for various reasons.

Comment: Hi RonJohn, one of my problems are that though I am a Canadian citizen, I am generally not a resident of Canada - at least not long enough to open meaningful relationships with banks, etc since that usually required extensive back and forth and a lot of delays in the on-boarding process.

Comment: Another issue I have is that Computershare in the UK will not liquidate the shares unless I can provide a domestic bank account in my name, which I do not have.  And since the shares are paper certificated, they cannot be transferred to an online broker to sell.  I am currently looking into whether a UK lawyer may be able to liquidate the shares for me.  Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Could you open a prepay card account such as https://www.cashplus.com/landing/personal/free-card/ (there are many others - check individual terms and conditions) which allows BACS deposits into the account. Also, if you just want to get rid of the shares, some charities will accept paper certificates.

Comment: Hello Owain,  thanks for the suggestion.  My experience with pre-pay cards has been that any deviation from ‘regular’ use of the card can quickly trigger balance freezes.  Because of this, I would not be comfortable with this option.  Also, I would not donate the shares.  I do wonder whether I could deposit the share value to a prepaid card, despite that I would not be comfortable doing this.  Is that a realistic option (it would be my only option at this point if it is).